# How to connect ESXi vm console from ESXi host console

Tags: esxi, ovf

Trying to automate ovf installation on a ESXi server.
I am able to deploy the ovf using ovftool then when I powered-on that vm it ask for input immidiatelly in boot console.

```
/vmfs/volumes/Datastore-3/vmware-ovftool/ovftool -dm=thin -ds=<datastore> --acceptAllEulas  "<ovf_path>" "vi://<username>:<password>@<esx host>"
```

Note : I am using a custom OVF which ask for inptu before starting boot process.

if I use vSphare clinet to connect to guest vm then I can interact with that VM console and provide required input.

But I need to do it from command line.
As I need to automate the process of OVF deploy and system configuration.

I can easily login to ESXi host termimal via SSH.
But how to get VM terminal from ESXi host terminal.

In some blog I found that the defaule terminal of Guest VM is serial.

I have also tried PowerCLI tool but no luck!!

Answer (score 2):

you can try [vmrc.exe](https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/details?downloadGroup=VMRC90&productId=491)

It can be used to get console of ESXi guest VM without using vSphare Client.

But as per your requirement, I think its not fully automatiable.
Once you get the remote console you need to do some GUI automation to interact with Guest VM console.

Example of vmrc.exe command :

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Remote Console\vmrc.exe" vmrc://<ESXi host username>@<ESXi host IP>/?moid=<VM ID>
```